# How do you upload a dataset from a zip file to an s3 bucket without downloading the zip file to your hard drive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Problem:
The data I need is in a zip file on a website, however, the zip file is too big to download onto my laptop.

How I think one can solve the problem:
Upload a zip file onto an s3 bucket without downloading the zip file in the laptop.

Goal: 
Get the zip file onto an s3 bucket, unzip the file on s3 bucket, use the command line in s3 to view the unzipped file's contents, therefrom extract CSV (or other sort of data convertible into CSV) for a project.

What I think can be done to solve this problem:
Use AWS Lambda to get the zip file from the website, therefore creating a temporary storage space on AWS Lambda; put file from AWS Lambda into an s3 bucket; unzip the file on s3; explore the contents of unzipped file on s3 bucket; extract what I need into another s3 bucket and then use those chosen contents from the unzipped file on SageMaker.

Comment: If the ZIP file is too large to download to your laptop, it will not fit into the available Lambda diskspace. Look at streaming the file (requires no diskspace), or launching a short-term EC2 instance to retrieve the file, unzip locally, upload to S3 as needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to "unzip on S3"  as Amazon S3 is an object storage service.

The easy and more expensive technique would be to spin up an Amazon EC2 instance, download the file onto the Amazon EBS volume, unzip and use `aws s3 sync` to upload the unzipped content to S3.

If you need to perform that operation frequently, you can use the AWS Lambda approach you described, which will be more cost effective.  But you will be limited by the available disk space for temporary storage of the Lambda function.

I would consider using **streaming API**.  You can stream from the source, unzip on the fly and upload to S3.

Multiple libraries exist to handle the streaming unzip operation (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip-stream for NodeJS for example)

S3 natively supports streaming using multi-part uploads, as does the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).